# Pause iteration of a for loop?

Tags: javascript, loops

I'd like to add a 1000ms pause between iterations of a for loop. All the solutions I have seen here, of which there are many, simply throw the loop into a function and call that from a `setTimeout` which just waits then executes the loop at speed. I need it to pause **inside** the loop. Here's a fiddle.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/erxp9Lpa/)

```
var button = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
var searchText = 'Activate';
var resultDiv = document.getElementById('results');

for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
  if (button[i].textContent == searchText) {
    button[i].click();
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = 'Clicked';
    div.className = 'click';
    resultDiv.append(div);
    // pause before iterating
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you.

```js
var button = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
var searchText = "Activate";
var resultDiv = document.getElementById('results');

for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
  (function(j) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (button[j].textContent == searchText) {
        button[j].click();
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = 'Clicked';
        div.className = 'click';
        resultDiv.append(div);
      }
    }, j * 1000);
  })(i);
};
```

```css
.wrapper {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.click {
  padding: 5px
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span>Activate</span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span>Activate</span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span>Activate</span>
  <span>Activate</span>
  <span></span>
  <span>Activate</span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span>Activate</span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span>Activate</span>
  <span></span>
  <span>Activate</span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span>Activate</span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
<div id="results">
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome. I'm trying to refactor it so the delay only happens after the click (when textContent===searchText)... but speeds through the other spans at full speed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setInterval() like:

```
 setInterval(function () {
            if (button[i].textContent == searchText) {
    button[i].click();
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = 'Clicked';
    div.className = 'click';
    resultDiv.append(div);
    // pause before iterating
  }
  if(i==button.length){
    clearInterval()
  }
  i++;
}, 2000);
```